# Display Related Object Using Custom Button(Java Script)

Tags: custom-button

[image: Error][image: Error Screenshot[![Here WhatID is the formula field which contain the related obj ID]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5weaj.png)I am trying to display related opportunities record related to particular account using a custom button over account detail page.

To achieve this requirement, i have created a formula field over opp. object that will store related object ID, and then created a dynamic report where i have filter data based on the formula field.

But when i click on view All Opportunities button over account page it is throwing error. Please see the attached screenshot for the same.Error1 [image: Custom Button definition]

Code :

```
{! REQUIRESCRIPT ("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")};
{! REQUIRESCRIPT ("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}
var recordIDs = '{!Account.Id}';
// Get Opportunity records related to account
Var results = sforce.connection.query ("Select Id,AccountID, from Opportunity where AccountID='{!Account.Id}'");
results = results.getArray ("records");
var recId;
for(var i = 0;i< results.length;i++){
    recId = results[i].Id;
    recordIds = recordIds +","+recId.substring(0,15);
}
var reportId = '{!$Label.ViewAllOpportunitiesReportID}';
window.open("/"+reportId+"?pv0="+recordIds,"_blank");
window.parent.location='/'+'{!Account.Id}';
```

Comment: Error is not clear in the picture. Also, put your code separately amending your question

Answer (score 1):

Two problems in your JavaScript are:

```
var recordIDs = ...

Var results = ...
```

should be this:

```
var recordIds = ...

var results = ...
```

because *JavaScript is a case sensitive language*.

Pasting your JavaScript code into http://jshint.com/ is one way to find problems like this. Or when JavaScript things go wrong, you can use your browser's Developer Tools such as the messages that appear in the JavaScript console.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want  to display all the Opportunities related to an Account when you click on button at Account Detail page.

So, create an Opportunity Report and pass the AccountId. You cannot pass a list of opportunities like the way you are passing.

[image: OpportunityId]

Comment: Hi Santanu,

I have updated the error screenshot, and in report i am passing the accountID only, as i have created a formula field on Opp. object which contain the value of accountID.